# Autoplay for Adobe Bridge Web Gallery Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, flash, web, adobe-bridge

Does anyone know how to set the adobe bridge web gallery slideshow to start playing automatically as soon as loaded?
I've made a Bridge web Gallery in Adobe Bridge CS5 and it suits perfectly on my website, all I wanna do is to let it autoplay without having the user push "Play" button.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally used the gallery, but I'm guessing it uses HTML, CSS and Javascript.

First thing you could do is check the documentation in case there is a JS property like this:

```
autoStart:false,
```

that you could change to true. If not, somewhere in your JS file or script you should be able to locate the function for the play button. You could move that to the page load. Suppose you have:

```
$('#play').click(function () {
     /// take the play function from here
}
```

Instead of calling it in the play, call it in the document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     /// paste the play function here
}
```